# MySQL Updating missing value in one table using the values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have null values in table 1:

```
 DATE_      ID       Sales
2007-01     1        NULL
2007-02     2        100
2007-03     3        200
2007-04     4        NULL
```

and the in table 2 I have :

```
 DATE_      ID       Sales
2007-01     1        99
2007-02     2        100
2008-03     3        200
2009-04     4        300
```

How do I update the null values in table one with matching DATE_ and ID.
I used

```
update table1 
set table1.sales = table2.sales
where table1.DATE_ = table2.DATE_
and table1.ID = table2.ID
```

but I got an error code: 1054, undefined column 'table2.ID' in 'where clause'.
I'm using MySQL.

Comment: it must be a typo or something similar. it should workl.

Comment: Put quotes around the names. I suspect  the underscore is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a inner joij

```
  update table1 
  inner join table2 on table1.DATE_ = table2.DATE_ 
     and table1.ID = table2.ID  
     and table1.sales is null 
  set table1.sales = table2.sales
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
update table1 set table1.sales = (select table2.sales where table1.DATE_ = table2.DATE_ and table1.ID = table2.ID)
```